# How to extract calculations/data from other large excel files +1 000 000 rows?

Tags: excel

**Background**
I've been assigned the task to figure out how to make a certain process more automated. Today we have a large excel file, always with the maximum amount of rows (+ 1 000 000). The file consist of much more account numbers than I am in use of looking into.

**Data-type**
The data is basically a lot of rows containing information regarding different accounts. There is transaction type, amount, account number, date and reference.

**Tried Solutions**
Previously I've tried several different solutions, see below.
1 - I created a macro loop, that for each account number selects the entire rows and tried to make calculations based on that. I didn´t get it working properly.
2 - With Macro I opened the largefile and tried to calculate by using this  If table_data(i - 1, 1) = "Credit" And table_data(i - 1, 10) < 0 And table_data(i - 1, 3) = (Account) Then... This worked, BUT - it calculated wrong. When I made the larger file smaller, it calculated correctly but as soon as I tried it on the larger file it calculates incorrectly.

I also tried by creating Power Query and Power Pivot, I am not that familiar to DAX syntax and my previously tasks with Power Query tends to crash after a while as many large connections and pivot tables makes the file impossible to work with.

**Mission**
What I would like to do is to have two separate workbooks, like summary.xlsm and then the other file largedata.xlsm. Then I would like to, from the summary file extract calculations such as sumifs/countifs from the largedata file. The biggest problem isn´t the functions or macro itself, but it is the fact that the file I need to gather the information from is soo large. Basically I want one summary file with 100 account numbers, and next to them I would like to have average balance, opening balance and so on for each account. And this information should be withdrawn/extracted from the larger file. Worth to add is that this should be done on a monthly basis, so the summary file should be as small as possible.

**Question**
How would you solve this?

Comment: I would probably not use Excel anymore for storing data, since the file is too big and it's purpose it's not anymore to do simple calculations. For storing data, databases are used, not Excel files. MS Access is probably already available to you as it's part of the MS Office.

Comment: Well, I've tried Access database in other projects. I don't know if I am doing something wrong but my experience is that Excel manage to handle larger data much better. I am not even able to upload file this big with Access while it is possible with Excel.